Is recursively calling main from its own parameters (abusing sizeof with VLAs) standard C99?
Disclaimer: my question isn't practical at all, it's more a question about 2 codes which allegedly abuse the rules and somewhat compile (with more or less warnings / errors according to the compiler).
As far as I know, the following code is valid C99 :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t n = sizeof(int[printf("%s", "Hello")]);
}

I understand that sizeof doesn't evaluate an expression unless it is a VLA (because it has non-constant size).
However, I'm not sure if this other piece of code is valid C99 :
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv);
int main(int argc, char* argv[sizeof(int[printf("%s\n", "Hello") + main(0, NULL)])]) {}

Run it on Compiler Explorer

Is it valid to have an array of size sizeof(some VLA) ?
Is it valid to have a declaration like int main(int, char**) and a definition like int main(int, char*[some size]) ?
And is it valid to recursively call a function from its own parameters ?
Is it guaranteed the recursion will happen or the compiler has the right to optimize it out ? If the recursion will happen, is it guaranteed there will be a stack overflow ?

I guess making an array of size sizeof(VLA) is valid, I know no rule which would make this invalid.
If I remember correctly, char*[some size] as function parameter decays to char**, but I don't know if it's ill-formed because the declaration/definition don't perfectly match.
And I have no idea if recursively call main from its parameters is valid or not, I obviously didn't find any resource or example of a code like this. Also, does main have different rules than other functions about recursive calls in the parameters ?
I guess the compiler may not optimize it out (I guess it's not an UB), so I also think a stack overflow will always happen.
Quotes from the standard would be very appreciated, thanks a lot.

I would have thought the disallowed part was calling main. As I understood things a recursive cqall to main is, in fact, disallowed, having nothing to do with VLA at all.

@SoronelHaetir In C++ it is disallowed. In C there is no such restriction.

The declaration of a parameter as an array is adjusted to make the parameter a pointer. This discards the array size expression, and the C standard contains no explicit statement about whether it is evaluated. GCC and Clang have historically disagreed about this. The compiler might not evaluate it.

Note that you can avoid the infinite recursion by using something like argc ? this : that to choose whether to make a further recursive call or not.

@EricPostpischil Regarding adjustment, the compiler must at least first conclude that the array is a valid declaration and that it is not an incomplete type (array declaration constraints "The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type") and that it doesn't have size zero (array declaration: "If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression... /--/  "otherwise, each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.") I'm not sure how the compiler can conclude such without evaluating the array size expression?

@Lundin: That is not in a constraints section, so the compiler is not required to diagnose it. The behavior is simply undefined, which means the standard allows any behavior, including not diagnosing the violation and not evaluating the expression.

@EricPostpischil Actually it says further down in the same paragraph I quoted (semantics) that "Where a size expression is part of the operand of a sizeof operator and changing the value of the size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not the size expression is evaluated." That's very much the case here thanks to array adjustment.

@Lundin: That means if you have something like sizeof (char (*)[foo()]), the foo() may or may not be evaluated because it will not change the result of the sizeof expression; it will be the size of a pointer to an array, regardless of the size of the array. That is not the case here; the value resulting from the sizeof expression would vary depending on the array size.

@EricPostpischil Hmm okay yeah so that's regardless of the result of sizeof happening to get passed to an outer array size declaration in this case. Still the text is strange because it implies that if the value affects the result of the operator, then the expression is evaluated. Or why else would they write it, if it is undefined/unspecified either way.



Is it valid to have an array of size sizeof(some VLA) ?


Yes.
The primary relevant provisions of C99 were:


[...] the [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they
delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant
expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. [...]
An ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3) that has a variably
modified type shall have either block scope and no linkage or function
prototype scope. If an identifier is declared to be an object with
static storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array
type.

(C99 6.7.5.2/1-2)

Note that the only constraint on the makeup of the expression designating the array size, if present, is that it have integer type.  The usage context places no other requirements on the operators or operands involved.


If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has
a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array
type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.
If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope,
it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise, each time it is
evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each
instance of a variable length array type does not change during its
lifetime. Where a size expression is part of the operand of a sizeof
operator and changing the value of the size expression would not
affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not
the size expression is evaluated.

(C99 6.7.5.2/4-5)

Note that the last sentence of that does not apply to your particular case; I include it for completeness, since it does involve mixing sizeof and VLAs.
The only additional requirement here is that the value be greater than 0, but that is always true of sizeof expressions (there are no zero-size objects).


Is it valid to have a declaration like int main(int, char**) and a definition like int main(int, char*[some size]) ?


Yes.
The primary relevant provisions of C99 were:


All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or
function shall specify compatible types.

(C99 6.7/4)

Note that multiple declarations of the same function are contemplated.


For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
return types. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present,
shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis
terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types.
[...] (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite
type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as
having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified
type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

(C99 6.7.5.3/15)

Note in particular that the comparison of parameter types uses the adjusted type.  This refers to

A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type'', where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.
(C99 6.7.5.3/7)

That adjustment moots the difference between your char** and char*[some size] where they appear as the types of function parameters.


And is it valid to recursively call a function from its own parameters ?


It depends.
C99 does not allow calls to undeclared functions (though many compilers accept these as a backwards-compatibility extension), and a function identifier is not in scope until immediately after its declaration is complete.  Thus an expression in a function declaration cannot call that function unless there is another declaration of the same function preceding it.  That usually is not the case, but your example takes care to provide for it.
Otherwise, as already discussed, the only limitation on the form of the size expression in a VLA is that it have integer type.  This is not limited by the context in which the VLA declaration appears.


Is it guaranteed the recursion will happen or the compiler has the right to optimize it out ?


No.
The primary provision here is

The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
[...]

At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.

[...]
(C99 5.1.2.3/5)

This is the primary provision about what optimizations may be performed overall.  Supposing we interpret printf() to produce output to a file (and that is the usual interpretation), it is not allowed to optimize away printf calls that emit any output at all.  However, the compiler is permitted to transform that from a recursion to a loop, for example.

If the recursion will happen, is it
guaranteed there will be a stack overflow ?

No.
Even if the compiler implements it as a recursion, the language spec says nothing about stack or stack overflow.  This is firmly in the area of implementation detail.
Moreover, even on an implementation that uses a call stack and therefore is conceivably susceptible to stack overflow, the compiler can avoid that in this particular case by observing that it is tail recursive, and therefore that each recursive call can reuse the same stack frame.

Thanks for the details about optimization, I didn't know this recursion could be converted into a loop.

@Chi_Iroh, every recursion can be converted into a loop, and vice versa.  But that conversion is pretty trivial in this particular case.  That's not always so.

@Chi_Iroh Read Lambda: The Ultimate GOTO

@JohnBollinger I realize I wasn't clear, I meant that I didn't know the optimizer was allowed to convert a recursion to a loop.

@Barmar Thanks for the link, I really like computers and programming history.

I think OP is implicitly asking whether the expressions in the function prototype may, or should, be evaluated. Which your answer doesn't explicitly address that I can see.  If we agree that they are not evaluated (as per the text you quote from C99 6.7.5.2/4-5) then the subsequent questions about recursion are moot, as there is no recursion in the posted code

@M.M You raise a good point. I think I wasn't very clear because the 2nd code I wrote as an example is very unusual and puzzling to me.
If I correctly understand your point, the expression 'printf("hello") + main(0, NULL)' shouldn't be evaluated ? Thus GCC, clang and others would be wrong ?

It's not actually tail-recursive. <expression> + <recursive call> has to perform the recursion then do the addition. While it's possible to translate any recursion into tail recursion, it requires some refactoring and I would not expect a compiler to do it automatically (think about how you would rewrite a normal factorial function tail-recursively).

@M.M, I took the question's "I understand that sizeof doesn't evaluate an expression unless it is a VLA (because it has non-constant size)" to mean, in part, that the OP recognizes that the operand of sizeof is evaluated when it is a VLA.  So no, I don't think that's what they are asking.

@Barmar, the OP's main() always returns 0, so the program does not need to recurse before adding.  Furthermore, the size expression's value is not actually used anyway because of function parameter adjustment -- it only needs to be evaluated for its side effects. I guess it's not tail recursive according to the abstract-machine semantics, but we only care in the context of optimization, and it shouldn't be much of a stretch for an optimizer to recognize that it can apply tail-call elimination.

In fact, I wouldn't be at all surprised if GCC's IL representation (for example) were genuinely tail-recursive.

@JohnBollinger In order for me to respond usefully to your last comment, can you explicitly state whether you agree that in the code being asked about int main(int argc, char* argv[sizeof(int[printf("%s\n", "Hello") + main(0, NULL)])]) {}  , the expression is not evaluated? (As defined by the standard quote you posted, C99 6.7.5.2/4-5).

How can the compiler conclude, before adjustment, that the array declaration is not an incomplete type or an array of size zero (both required by C17 6.7.6.2 array declarators), if the size parameter is not evaluated?

@M.M, that is an ambiguity in the spec: does the fact that the adjustment of the parameter type removes the expression imply that it is not evaluated?  But a common interpretation (by GCC, for example), is that it is evaluated.  This is the interpretation I am assuming. But the parameter-type adjustment does mean that the result of the evaluation goes unused.  If it were not evaluated at all then that would be the end of the matter, of course.

Is that directed to me, @Lundin?  I never said the size expression was not evaluated, and I think it is reasonably clear from this answer that I interpret the spec to say it is evaluated.  What I said is that the result is unused.  And also that the compiler knows the return value of this main() at compile time.

@Lundin . 6.7.6.3/4 says explicitly that the incomplete type condition is checked after adjustment.  It's not clear to me from the standard if checking for VLA size 0 happens before or after adjustment -- but seems a moot point as the behaviour for size 0 is UB no diagnostic required

@M.M Yes but in order to get to the after adjustment point, it must be a valid array declaration to begin with or it can't get adjusted. So the array declaration parts apply first - the same reason why we can't write parameters as int x[][]. I don't see why the compiler would block that but at the same time allow a VLA where the size gets evaluated to zero. It may very well be that neither the language nor the existing compilers make any sense here.

Really, @Lundin, you can't?  I think you're selling yourself short.  int x[][] violates a language constraint, whereas int x[n] with n evaluating non-positive at runtime violates (only) a semantic rule.  The former can be processed at compile time, and a conforming implementation must diagnose it.  The latter cannot be recognized until runtime, and if the implementation wants to affirmatively reject it then it has to emit instrumentation to do so.  That certainly could be done, but but I don't see why it would be when no array is actually being allocated.

But in fact, @Lundin, I don't think I accept that reaching parameter type adjustment requires that the VLA size evaluate positive.  Referring to C17 (though C99 says the same things), paragraph 6.7.6.2/3 uses the form of a declaration to specify that it declares an array.  A separate semantic rule (6.7.6.2/5) requires that the size expression evaluate positive (when evaluated at all), but that doesn't moot, supersede, or even modify /3.  Nor should it, because, again, the type category needs to be determined at compile time, but a variable dimension cannot be computed until runtime.


Is it valid to have an array of size sizeof(some VLA) ?

Sure. When declaring a VLA the size can be any expression. There's no reason why sizeof expressions would be prohibited.
char new_array[sizeof VLA];

is equivalent to
size_t n = sizeof VLA;
char new_array[n];


Is it valid to have a declaration like int main(int, char**) and a definition like int main(int, char*[some size]) ?

Yes. In a declaration they're equivalent.

And is it valid to recursively call a function from its own parameters ?

The function can be called any time after the declaration. So you just need a forward declaration, just like you would for a function defined after the function in which it's called.

Is it guaranteed the recursion will happen or the compiler has the right to optimize it out ?

The optimizer can optimize it out if it can determine that it won't change a well-defined result. If actually recursing would cause infinite recursion, and the optimizer can determine this, it can optimize it all out because it's allowed to assume there won't be any undefined behavior.

“from its own parameters” as in the example in the question, not as in using the same arguments.

@Barmar Thanks for the clear answer. I edited to ask another question about optimization and what the compiler is allowed to do, could you answer about it ? Also, I wondered about recursion because I thought when in the parameters, the function doesn't really exist, so maybe different rules would apply.

The optimizer is allowed to do anything that doesn't change the result.

Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "from its own parameters". I thought you meant "using its own parameters"

Thank you for the edit, it answers everything now.

As far as I am aware, C99 does not insist that programs terminate, nor does it forbid unbounded recursion in particular.  There can be programs that a given C implementation fails to execute consistently with the spec, and some with deep or unbounded recursion are typically among them, but that does not make the behavior of such programs undefined.  To the best of my knowledge, the spec does not license compilers to optimize away infinite recursion.

Re “The optimizer can optimize it out if it can determine that it won't change a well-defined result”: This is either incorrect or incomplete, depending on the definition of “well defined.” Some conforming programs have multiple allowed behaviors defined by the C standard. For example, programs containing indeterminately sequenced evaluations may have multiple allowed behaviors. It may be, in some programs, that a recursion can be optimized away even if that changes the behavior, from one allowed behavior to another.

@EricPostpischil If you can come up with a better one-sentence summary of when optimization is allowed, I'll replace it. Otherwise, I don't think this is the place for a treatise on the theory of optimization.

@Barmar: Questions tagged language-lawyer are the place for treatises on optimization.

“The optimizer can optimize it out if it the resulting observable behavior is the same as for an unoptimized implementation of the program.”

@EricPostpischil Doesn't that have the same problem if there are multiple allowed behaviors? The optimizer can switch it from one to another.

@Barmar: If there are multiple allowed behaviors, then the program may be implemented as a program A with one behavior or as a program B with another behavior or possibly more. Saying the optimizer can optimize something out if the resulting behavior is the same as for an unoptimized implementation of the program allows for the behavior to be the same as implementation A or the same as optimization B and so on.


Is it guaranteed the recursion will happen or the compiler has the right to optimize it out ? If the recursion will happen, is it guaranteed there will be a stack overflow ?

There's a clause in the spec that says:

If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by *

C99: 6.7.5.2/5
That implies that your code example is equivalent to
int main(int argc, char* argv[*])]) {}

and that the expression in the size should not be evaluated at all.  However, it seems that gcc does not conform to this.

Function prototype scope is only for a function declaration that is not a definition. int main(int argc, char* argv[*])]) {} does not contain anything in function prototype scope. Its parameter declarations are in block scope associated with the main function body, {}.

There is no clause 6.7.5.2.5 in the C standard. There is a paragraph 5 in clause 6.7.2.5. Paragraphs should not be cited the way you have because it fails to distinguish clause 6.7.6.2 from clause 6.7.6 paragraph 2.

@EricPostpischil Is §6.7.5.2/5 correct ?

@Chi_Iroh: It resolves the ambiguity problem. Whether to use /, ¶, space, or something else is a matter of aesthetics. I generally prefer to match the original source in its use of parentheses, periods, or other markings to distinguish parts of the document. The C standard does not use any markings to distinguish paragraphs other than position on the page, effectively white-space separated from the clause numbers, so I just use a space, as in “6.7.2.5 5”.

Makes sense, thank you for the explanation. I have just submitted an edit.

I guess you're correct on the precise definition of "function prototype scope", but then it still leaves the question as to when or even if the expression needs to be evaluted.  VLA sizes are only needed when VLAs are created, or when sizeof is evaluated on a (non-parameter) VLA, so there's never a need to evaluate it for function parameter declarations.
